# Erro desconhecido na integração com WebService REST

Tags: delphi, rest, exceção

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição do tipo POST usando os componentes: RESRRequest, RESTClient, RESTResponse pelo Delphi Xe8.

Na integração do tipo GET eu consigo fazer normalmente, recebo o retorno normalmente do servidor.

Porém, ao fazer a integração via POST está dando uma excessão na execução: "Execution of request terminated with unknown error".

Pode ser que eu esteja errando em alguma coisa. O servidor espera 2 parâmetros:

```
1 - HeaderParam, tipo AlfaNumérico, Identificador "Token-Integracao"
2 - BodyParam, tipo Complexo, Identificador "itensResolvidos"
```

Segue o código que estou usando para fazer a integração:

```
with fDm do
begin
  sRet := EmptyStr;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := sInfo[7];
  RESTClient.Params.ParameterByName('Token-Integracao').Value := sInfo[6];

  with RESTClient.Params.AddItem do
  begin
    name := 'itensResolvidos';
    Value := sJson; // String com o JSON a ser enviado, montado anteriormente
    Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY;
  end;

  RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Execute; // Aqui dá a Excessão e não continua o programa

  sRet := '{"retorno":' + RESTResponse.JSONValue.ToString + '}';
end;
```

Comment: Para o token tens que criar um parâmetro do tipo cabeçalho, faz o mesmo que você fez para criar o parâmetro para itens resolvidos só que no tipo escolha pkHTTPHEADER. Pois o retorno espera o token via cabeçalho.

Comment: O token eu criei diretamente no componente, pois estou utilizando o componente RESTCliente para fazer o GET, e deu certo. Mesmo assim vou fazer o que você disse, criar da mesma forma que o outro pra ver se é isso. Obrigado!

Comment: Qualquer coisa, tente fazer o teste pelo Postman

Comment: Coloquei o Token da mesma forma, não resolveu. Estou indo atrás de testar pelo Postman. Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constumo utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
RESTClient.BaseURL := MINHA_URL;
Requisicao.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
Requisicao.Resource := '/REQUISICAO_QUALQUER';
Requisicao.Params.AddItem('username', aUsuario, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
Requisicao.Params.AddItem('password', aSenha, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
Requisicao.Execute;
```

`TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;` este deve resolver seu problema.

Tanto para `GET` quanto para `POST` deve ser especificado para cada parâmetro o que esta fazendo. No caso, eu utilizo o `pkGETorPOST`.

Quanto ao Token o envio é da seguinte forma:

```
Requisicao.Params.AddItem('Authorization'
                          ,SEU_TOKEN
                          ,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER
                          ,[poDoNotEncode]
                          ,ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

Quanto ao JSON o envio é da seguinte forma:

```
Requisicao.AddBody(SEU_JSON, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: Júnior, adaptei algumas coisas que estavam faltando, porém mesmo assim ainda não resolveu. O erro desconhecido ainda aparece. Pelo POSTMAN eu consegui, mas ainda não sei o que eu preciso fazer no Delphi para que funcione corretamente. Continuarei fazendo testes e retornarei aqui para dizer o resultado. Muito obrigado até aqui

Comment: Júnior, consegui! Eu estava cometendo um erro de iniciante aqui! às vezes tenho vergonha por não ter prestado atenção a algo simples que eu estava errando... Do seu jeito deu certo. Muito obrigado!